# Imbedding of $SU(2)$ in the exceptional Lie group $E_7$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

We consider the classical Lie groups  so that that center of the covering space is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. From the list of simple Lie groups it follows that they are:

$SO(2k+1)$ (case B)  for $k\ge 1$ or $Sp(k)$ for $ k\ge 3$ (case C).

In fact in case (A) we also have $SU(2)$ but this is isomorphic to $SO(3)$. Then we take the quotients of the above groups by their centers.  The obtained groups have the property:

(*)  There exists an embedding $f:SU(2)\subset M$ inducing isomorphisms of fundamental groups $f_{\#};\pi_1(SU(2))\to \pi_1M=\mathbb Z_2$ and of third cohomology groups $f^*: H^3(M;\mathbb{Q})\to H^3(SU(2);\mathbb{Q})$

This follows from the natural fiberings of these groups over the spheres.

On the other hand there is also one exceptional group $E_7$ with $\pi_1 E_7=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Does it also have (*) property?

Comment: SU(2) and SO(3) are only locally isomorphic, and the former is simply connected. So do you mean for M to be simply connected as well?

Comment: Related to @DavidRoberts comment. I thought you meant $M$ to be the quotient of the Lie group by its two element center. In that case I believe that the $SU(2)$ on the left hand side of $f_\sharp$ should really be $SO(3)$ because $\pi_1(SO(3)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ but $\pi_1(SU(2)) = \{1\}$ so $f_\sharp$ would not be an isomorphism when using $SU(2)$.

Comment: Sorry for being not accurate. By $M$ I mean a simple Lie group divided by its center. So the question is

Comment: Sorry once more. Here $M$ denotes a simple Lie group divided by its center. So the question is
    
    (*) Does there exist an embedding of $f:SO(3) \to E_7$ inducing isomorphisms of fundamental groups and of third cohomology groups $f^*:H^3(E_7;\mathbb{Q})\to H^3(SO(3);\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: @user46230 can you edit the question above to make it self-contained, and also self-consistent?